# Select multiple equals from same table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Creating a database search system that searches for an input value but with a fixed element from a dropdown using php and mysql

e.g.

```
SELECT * from mytable where fname LIKE '%INPUT%' or lname LIKE '%INPUT%' and city = 'Dublin';
```

The problem is only the last part is being executed, the results display everything from Dublin and ignores the first part.

How do I structure my query properly?

Answer (score 4):

`a OR b AND c` may not evaluate as you want:

```
SELECT 1 OR 0 AND 0;
-- 1
```

Instead: `(a OR b) AND c` where:

```
SELECT (1 OR 0) AND 0;
-- 0
```

Comment: Logically Useful Answer +1

Comment: This doesn't work like operator precedence so I too accept @tadman 's answer

Comment: After a little bit of tweaking this worked great! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SQL follows the same order of Boolean operators that you see elsewhere. You have to use parenthesis to enforce the type of grouping I think you want. `A or B and C` as you have it evaluates to `A or BC`. Try the following:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (fname LIKE '%INPUT%' OR lname LIKE '%INPUT%') AND city = 'Dublin';`

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple logic problem (if I am understanding your needs correctly).

```
SELECT * from mytable 
        where (fname LIKE '%INPUT%' or lname LIKE '%INPUT%') and city = 'Dublin';
```

Should fix your problem.

You are wanting the results where the input is like fname or lname and the city is Dublin, however, due to [order of operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql), AND is executed before OR.  So you are really asking (in your original query) for the situation where the lname is like the input AND the city is Dublin, OR the fname is like the input.

We fix this by using Parenthesis, as shown, because they then are evaluated before the AND, as Parenthesis have a higher order in execution.

Answer (score 0):

In Boolean arithmetic, AND takes precedence over OR (like multiplications and divisions take precedence over sums and subtractions in normal arithmetic).

In your where clause, you write:

```
fname LIKE '%INPUT%' or lname LIKE '%INPUT%' and city = 'Dublin'
```

which defaults to this:

```
fname LIKE '%INPUT%' or (lname LIKE '%INPUT%' and city = 'Dublin')
```

But you probably want to do this (you have to use the parenthesis):

```
(fname LIKE '%INPUT%' or lname LIKE '%INPUT%') and city = 'Dublin'
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of it, I assume that you want to retrieve entries which have Dublin as the city **and** the lastname or the firstname matching your string.

That's not what you wrote, since **`AND`** has a higher precedence (it's resolved before) than **`OR`**.

You should try this :

```
SELECT * from mytable where (fname LIKE '%INPUT%' or lname LIKE '%INPUT%') and city = 'Dublin';
```